# Is there a way to trigger the 'magic caret' feature on ios (web)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a js virtual keyboard that is able to update the value of a textarea. On mobile, you can trigger the 'magic floating caret' by holding down on a textarea or holding any key on the native keyboard. Because my textarea input mode is set to none in order to hide the native keyboard and show my own, I'd like to know if there is a way to trigger that second effect using my own keyboard?

My understanding is that I can trigger an event using execCommand or jQuery's trigger function, but neither are able to do what I'd like.

Thanks for input!

[magic cursor article link news18](https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/a-hidden-feature-on-iphone-to-move-the-cursor-is-blowing-everyones-mind-1944215.html)

Comment: Could you please explain what this *magic floating caret* is? An internet search of these terms only throws results about Aladin's magic floating carpet...

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Added in edit but here is the link to what I'm referencing: https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/a-hidden-feature-on-iphone-to-move-the-cursor-is-blowing-everyones-mind-1944215.html